# angularjs switch tab view using ui.bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui.bootstrap

I have set up two buttons to switch to other two tabs on click, but it is not working.

here is the html code:

```
<div ng-controller="TabCtrl">
    <uib-tabset class="tabbable">
        <uib-tab heading="my tab 0" ng-attr-active="tabs[0].active">
            <div class="row">

            <a class="btn btn-wide btn-azure" ng-click="go_tab1()">
            Go To tab 1
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-wide btn-azure" ng-click="go_tab2()">
            Go To tab 2
            </a>
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="my tab 1" ng-attr-active="tabs[1].active">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="my tab 2" ng-attr-active="tabs[2].active">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

**here is the controller:**

```
$scope.tabs = [{active: true}, {active: false}, {active: false}];
$scope.go_tab1 = function() {
    $scope.tabs[1].active = true;
};
$scope.go_tab2 = function() {
    $scope.tabs[2].active = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine if you add the correct libraries

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
   <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
```

and injecting the ui.bootstrap dependency.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('TabCtrl', function($scope) {
  
$scope.tabs = [{active: true}, {active: false}, {active: false}];
$scope.go_tab1 = function() {
    $scope.tabs[1].active = true;
};
$scope.go_tab2 = function() {
    $scope.tabs[2].active = true;
};

});
```

```html
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
   <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="TabCtrl">

  <uib-tabset class="tabbable">
        <uib-tab heading="my tab 0" ng-attr-active="tabs[0].active">
            <div class="row">

            <a class="btn btn-wide btn-azure" ng-click="go_tab1()">
            Go To tab 1
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-wide btn-azure" ng-click="go_tab2()">
            Go To tab 2
            </a>
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="my tab 1" ng-attr-active="tabs[1].active">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="my tab 2" ng-attr-active="tabs[2].active">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have question related to your answer. If you add content inside tabs it will not display the last tab content no matter how much tabs you have. Only last tab wont show content. Why is that ?

Comment: @StefanJovanic : Could you point me to the question, i will have a look or provider a jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: Sorry for disturbance, I found out what was the issue. I had old custom css with tabs that I created and accidentally happened that names were exactly same as in bootstrap. Can you belive that ?  And for some reason I had display last child set to none. My apologies.

Comment: @StefanJovanic No Problem. Glad that you caught the issue.